# Rails conditions for includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :order_items
    has_many :orders, through: :order_items
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :item
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :order_items
    has_many :items, :through => :order_items
end
```

I have a helper method 'current_order' for each user.

```
Item.includes(:order_items)
```

Return all order_items.

I need all items with includes :order_items with condition 'order_id = current_order'.

Comment: You can just do `current_order.items` ... that should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "with includes :order_items" but the answer is simple:

```
Order.where(order_id: current_order).items
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `includes` for `current_order`.

Basically, `includes` is supposed to prevent `N+1 queries` problem which happens when you have multiple records from one table and you try to get an association for each record.

In your case, `current_order` will run a single query:

```
select * from orders where order_id = 1
```

and `current_order.items` will just run another query:

```
select * from order_items where order_id = 1
```